# get last frame of a vedio clip and extend for 10 scends using moviepy

Tags: python, moviepy

I'm using `moviepy` to edit some video clips. I want to play the last frame of orginal clip for 10 seconds, so that I could display some text on it. I tried to convert last frame to video by using

```
clip.to_ImageClip(t=clip.duration).set_duration(10)
```

but failed.

Does anyone konw why? And any possible solutions.

```
import moviepy.editor as ed
import os

content=ed.VideoFileClip(path)
myclip=content.to_ImageClip(content.duration).set_duration(10)
myclip.write_videofile(path)
```

MoviePy error:

```
failed to read the first frame of video file C:\my\test.mp4. 

That might mean that the file is corrupted. 
That may also mean that you are using a deprecated version of FFMPEG. 
On Ubuntu/Debian for instance the version in the repos is deprecated. 
Please update to a recent version from the website.
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @user3475182 does work and gets a clip consisting of the last frame repeated. To extend the entire video you give the program you need to concatenate the original and the generated video content and then export that video.

Here is the full code,

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips
import os

# Extend a clip by 4 seconds
clip = VideoFileClip(*pathToVideoFile*)
frame_t = clip.duration - 1
ext_clip = clip.to_ImageClip(t=frame_t, duration=4)
concat_clip = concatenate_videoclips([clip, ext_clip])
concat_clip.write_videofile("sample4.mp4", fps=24)
```

Answer (score -1):

I was too facing the same issue, however, the below code worked for me:

```
clip = VideoFileClip(path)
frame_t = clip.duration - 1
ext_clip = clip.to_ImageClip(t=frame_t, duration=4)
ext_clip.write_videofile("sample4.mp4", fps=24)
```